# Android signed apk - Keystore

Tags: java, android

I am creating a new thread as I could not fix my problem from existing threads and googling.

I just finished my new update of one of my published apps. I tried to generate a signed apk with the same keystore I always use and ofcourse the passwords that I had save in a txt file. But when I try to sign the apk, **I get an error**

> java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was
>   incorrect

Since I am sure about the passwords, how can I fix this error? I really do not want to delete my app and make a fresh one.

Tank you in advance.

Comment: Try restoring to a `previous version` of the `.key` file if you are running *Windows*.

Comment: What do you mean a previous version? The keystore is supposed to be the same until the end of the updates. Am I wrong? By the way, how I do that?

Comment: It is just a work around if your .key file has encountered some malformation due to electronic shenanigans. Right click on the file and then select `Restore to a previous version`

Comment: Well just tried but there are no previous versions of the file. Tried to sign again and still nothing. Am I doomed?

Comment: Do you have any restore points under `System Restore` ?

Comment: have you tried the `-importkeystore ` for keytool command? check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535424/android-keystore-stopped-working at end of question where it says **Solution (6/29/14):** good luck

Comment: @CodeWalker i don't think System Restore saves any user data, it only save points for OS settings and so ...

Comment: @Yazan I did not try this. But, I think it will ask for password again, correct? The problem is that every command I used in cmd, everytime asks for password and ofcourse it says password wrong. The funny think is that when I brute force the keystore, I get again the password I put.

Comment: yes, i know but give it a try, when you sign an app may be some other parts of the file is corrupted, so you can't, but this method might allow you to extract the key into a file, then create a new JKS with the same key, give it a try cuz if it works, it's way better than using new key and replace your app on store :)

Comment: @Yazan Well friend, it asks for password as I said and still the error occures. Any other ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: How old is the keystore? May be it was created using an now outdated algorithm. Try if you can open it with Portecle. It tries all available algorithms and your password.