# Android KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey lengthTag=109, too big

Tags: android, keytool

I've been trying to generate an .apk (debug or release) and I've been getting this error:

```
com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "/home/note-300/.android/debug.keystore": DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big.
```

I already tried creating a new key (with key and alias with the same name) on Android Studio, I deleted the .android/debug.keystore and run the following commands (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535424/android-keystore-stopped-working)):

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore old.keystore -destkeystore new.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12
```

and

```
 keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore new.keystore -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore final.keystore -deststoretype jks
```

What else can I do to run my app?

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Android Studio 3.3.1

Comment: You mention that you created the key using AS then deleted the keystore and recreated it using the command line, is that correct ? why not just create everything using AS tool, it's pretty straightforward?

Comment: @113408 I created the key on AS and got this error. Delete it and created again using command line, got the same error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try upgrading gradle from in the gradle-wrapper.properites file from 4.10.1 to 4.10.2. I had the same problem, and that fixed it for me.

Comment: After trying everything I could find, nothing worked.  Then I did two things that finally got me up any running.
1) Regenerated the keystore using this url: https://coderwall.com/p/r09hoq/android-generate-release-debug-keystores

I also used the suggested step to convert the jks to pkcs12, this step was provided when you run the keytool command. 

2) Then I created a new React Native app folder by doing react-native init myNewAppName

This time when I ran the react-native run-android everything build fine.

Comment: Thank you so much. It saved me a lot of time and effort.

Comment: Wow, thanks!  There was a Gradle upgrade message in AS and I accepted it and the signing worked again.

Answer (score 12):

Probably not the exact answer but the below steps solved my problem. Because I was already using gradle 4.10.2.

Steps:

1. Delete `.gradle` folder from android folder.
2. Run `react-native run-android`.

The above steps fixed the problem.